# How to manage memory in ios swift base app?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to develop an ios app which have a `ViewController` that show some details about a product and show's a demo video. 
at the bottom I suggest some other product which by clicking , navigate to same VC with different data.
Now, How could I manage my memory?(when navigation happen,memory usage increase badly because in previous vc demo video still exist).I use swift4 and `AVPlayer`.
my player code :

```
 if let videoURL = URL(string: url) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerView.frame.size.width, height: containerView.frame.size.height)
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        containerView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachTheEndOfTheVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
        play()
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: which part do u mean?that's my player

Comment: pause the video when you moveout of view controller

Comment: Are you sure that your player object is empty/nil after `deinit()`? Also are you removing the observer you added anywhere, pausing the player?

Answer (score 0):

You should stop your video when you leave your VC

In ViewWillDisappear method do

```
player.pause()
```